# Can you update a component from a button with ajax = false?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a button that makes a download and when clicking on the update another component(btnsFGC)
my xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Descargar CSV" 
icon="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" 
actionListener="#{biblioF2.setBanderaDescarga(true)}">
       <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="tablaDatos" fileName="libros" />
</p:commandButton>

 <h:panelGroup id="btnsFGC">
....
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to use something like Primefaces monitorDownload https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml plus a p:remoteCommand. Edit: if you want it to update onclick I believe you just need p:remoteCommand. Haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question but ... The whole point of using ajax is that you don't update the whole page, just parts of the page components instead. if you set up ajax to false, then the whole page will be updated. If you just want to update btnsFGC then do this:

set ajax in commandButton to true or take it out since the default value is true, then set update="btnsFGC" in the commandButton. this will only update the components specified by the update attribute. I will also use action instead of actionListener.

Comment: Afaik, you need `ajax="false"` for the dataExporter to work